# MSBuild randomly fail at start with access violation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

On our continuous integration, we build a bunch on programs and libraries in serie, using one MSBuild process per product (about 50 products to build). 
Often, we get a build failure on one of the product to build, but:
- it happens randombly on different products
- launching it again -> build success
- MSBuild fail before even starting compilation (in less than 1s)

We have these in the system logs:

```
Faulting application name: MSBuild.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x545443d5
Faulting module name: MSBuild.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x545443d5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0003cdbe
Faulting process id: 0x30b0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0d07d89f8c3f8
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
Report Id: c7ae6b54-3c70-11e5-80d1-b82a72d611be
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Return code is *-1073741819*

What could be causing this issue ? 
Is there anything we can do beside launching the build N time to have it success ?

Comment: I'd double check the hardware to rule that out. Are your disks alright?

Comment: It happens on different build server, but it's true that it happen more often on a specific one. 
Also, I have never seen it during work hour (but I can't say it never have), can it be related to another scheduled job launched during the night ?